# Detecting a docx page break in Pandoc

Tags: lua, pandoc

There are lots of answers about how to output a page break to `.docx` files with Pandoc, but is there any way to **detect** page breaks when reading from a `.docx`?

I know Pandoc's AST doesn't support the idea of a page break, but I'd been hoping to be able to use eg a Lua filter with a `RawBlock`:

```lua
function RawBlock (el)
  return pandoc.Str "PAGE BREAK"
end

return {
  {RawBlock = RawBlock}
}
```

However, that doesn't work (presumably because the page break is simply ignored, rather than turned into a `RawBlock`?)

The only solution I can think of is to pre-process the `.docx` using an XML parser and replace all instances of `<w:br w:type="page"/>` with a magic string, which we can then detect, but using a separate XML parser sort of defeats the point of using Pandoc in the first place.

Comment: try the newest pandoc version and do `pandoc input.docx -t native` to see all the things you can match on with a filter. If the pagebreak is not there, you'll indeed have to preprocess it...

Comment: Yeah sadly nothing in there.

Comment: Yeah, ultimately pandoc will have to add a pagebreak element to its AST, see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1934